# Is there Any free FingerPrint identification SDK Available in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint, biometrics

I am working on a fingerprint identification system project,Is there any free sdk available for fingerprint identification system?

Comment: I have a project coming up in this domain, so I'm also in the look out of related information. Have a look at this article -> [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38881/Fingerprint-Reader-Integration-using-the-M2SYS-SDK). There are many other related articles in the same site.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97590/A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification  is is helpful?

Comment: http://www.sourceafis.org  Is excellent, free and native to .net 4

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple free sdk's that I could find available at:

1. http://www.winsite.com/Development/Components-Libraries/Free-Fingerprint-Verification-SDK/
2. http://www.neurotechnology.com/free-fingerprint-verification-sdk.html

They are both based on Verifinger and have a limitation of storing only 10 records.

Comment: These links are to a product and should be be classified as spam.

Comment: @jwize Just because the link is to a product does not meen it is necessarily spam. It was an attempt to answer the question about a free sdk. It was what was available almost 5 years ago.

Comment: @jwize If you really went to the site, you should see that link 1 contains and SDK and additional code samples for you to run and learn from. For me, I think this should be the answer to this question because it has a free SDK for reading and comparing fingerprints